# Package subpath './markup.js' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, клавиатура, telegraf

```
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup.js')

function getMainMenu() {
    return Markup.keyboard([
        ['1', '2'],
        ['123']
    ]).resize().extra()
}
```

При импорте\запуске кода в котором импортируеться `markup` вылезает ошибка:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './markup.js' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\iamst\Desktop\Derpy_bot\node_modules\telegraf\package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\iamst\Desktop\Derpy_bot\keyboards.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\iamst\Desktop\Derpy_bot\bot.js:4:25) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы его require-ите? Он не описан в списке разрешённых

Comment: дам где я смотрел, там всегда рекваирили

Comment: Подозреваю что правильно так: `require('telegraf').Markup`

Comment: @AlexeyTen не знаете почему выдаёт ошибку `TypeError: Markup.keyboard(...).extra is not a function? `

Comment: А так?

`const Markup = require('telegraf/markup')`

Answer (score 0):

Сделай так и не парься`const {Markup} = require('telegraf')`, а по хорошему разберись в этом !

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]